# HTTP string request works in browser but not work with android volley request?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application i have a volley request that sends a large string (base64 image) to the web service. The request works well from the browser but it gives me the following error when i run it by the mobile.

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: I think some went wrong with html, not the volley. You may `check your Url` and refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623432/java-net-protocolexception-with-httpsurlconnection-in-android)